# InputStreamReader on a URL connection returning null

Tags: java, url, jsoup, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am following a tutorial on web scraping from the book "Web Scraping with Java". The following code gives me a nullPointerExcpetion. Part of the problem is that `(line = in.readLine())` is always null, so the while loop at line 33 never runs. I do not know why it is always null however. Can anyone offer me insight into this? This code should print the first paragraph of the wikipedia article on CPython.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WikiScraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scrapeTopic("/wiki/CPython");
    }
    public static void scrapeTopic(String url){
        String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/"+url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String contentText = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p").first().text();
        System.out.println(contentText);
    }
    public static String getUrl(String url){
        URL urlObj = null;
        try{
            urlObj = new URL(url);
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("The url was malformed!");
            return "";
        }
        URLConnection urlCon = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String outputText = "";
        try{
            urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                outputText += line;
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("There was an error connecting to the URL");
            return "";
        }
        return outputText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this question was downvoted, is there a way I can make the question more clear? I am trying to figure out how I can make the in.readline() command return something other than null and do not know how to explain my question further other than that the result of the whole program should be the first paragraph of the wikipedia article on CPython.

Comment: 'InputStreamReader` does not return null. `BufferedReader.readLine()` does, and the reason is documented. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter http://www.wikipedia.org//wiki/CPython in web browser, it will be redirected to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython, so

use `String html = getUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/"+url);`

instead `String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/"+url);`

then `line = in.readLine()` can really read something.

Comment: Thank-you, it appears that doc is assigned to some html code that makes sense for it, but I still receive a null pointer exception at the line `String contentText = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p").first().text();`

Comment: Can you tell me how the `(doc.select("#mw-content-text > p")` line is working exactly, because I think that this is the part that is returning null.

Comment: Or specifically just the `"#mw-content-text > p"` part

Comment: `doc.select("#mw-content-text > p) ` means select the p elements which are children of element with CSS id `mw-content-text`. You can view the source code of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython with web browser, since element `mw-content-text` has no children, `doc.select("#mw-content-text > p) `  return NULL.

Comment: @Jacob "Web Scraping with Java", Publication Date: August 26, 2013, the web page has changed since publication date, so the sample may not work.

Comment: Well it looks like everything works except for the part with > p, which I understand to be the p blocks that are children of blocks with the id "mw-content-text". I've checked and theres blocks with the id mw-content-text, that have p blocks as children, but I still get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Jacob  according to this, https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax,  use `#mw-content-text p` instead `#mw-content-text > p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163491/discussion-between-user27149-and-jacob).